# How to timeout a bash script with multiple commands?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that is executed by php. To avoid endless waiting or timeouts at the client side I want to stop the script after its been running a certain amount of time. The script contains many different commands and functions.

I found out you can use timeout with EOF but unfortunately it doesn't seem you can use variables inside timeout so something like the script below won't work.

```
echo "Starting script"

timeout 500s bash <<EOF
    echo "Running script"
    timeout="no"
    echo "$timeout"
EOF

echo "timeout: $timeout"

if [ "$timeout" = "no" ];
    then
        echo "Done"
    else
        echo "Timed out"
fi

exit
```

Is it possible for a shell script to check how long it has been running by itself and if a certain amount of time has passed do something? I don't want it to simply stop.

Comment: variables are set in a new process, which has his own environment ; so the caller's environment is not changed

Comment: If the shell script has a main loop, you can check the `$SECONDS` variable before/after each iteration. If it is just a bunch of calls to functions, you could check it before each function call.

Answer (score 0):

timeout forks a new process which current process will kill if not terminated after duration, so variables are set in a new process and can't be used in consecutive commands.

alternatively timeout may be set in a new process but in this case the whole process will be terminated after timeout

```
start_timeout() { (sleep "$1"; kill "$$") & timeout_pid=$!; }
end_timeout() { kill "$timeout_pid"; }
```

usage

```
start_timeout 10
command1
end_timeout

start_timeout 20
command2
end_timeout
```

but in that case if command1 times out the command2 is not executed